# Can a basketball player refuse to be chosen in a particular team?

Tags: rules, nba, draft

Is it possible that during the annual draft a basketball player do not accept the proposal from the team?
I mean, e.g. if during draft 2017 there are more teams that would like to choose Markelle Fultz but he would like to play only for Suns is it possible that he refuse any team to be free when Suns has its choose?